# Export into Microsoft Word in C#

Tags: c#

I am tried to create a Microsoft word document using C#, I have a data that is retrieved from the Database and then I convert it into table in the Microsoft word and save it . the problem when the document created , it is create a table with number of rows that equal the number of the rows in the table that I connect to from the database , not just the range that i detect it in the range in the code .
Ex: The Exams table has 7rows at all , and my condition retrieve just 4 rows, the code create document with 7 rows, 4 from it have information from the database and 3 are null rows.
and that my code :

```
 public void create_Document()
    {
        try
            {
                //Create an instance for word app
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

                //Set animation status for word application
                winword.ShowAnimation = false;

                //Set status for word application is to be visible or not.
                winword.Visible = false;

                //Create a missing variable for missing value
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                //Create a new document
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                //Add header into the document
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in document.Sections)
                {
                    //Get the header range and add the header details.
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
                    headerRange.Fields.Add(headerRange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
                    headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
                    headerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
                    headerRange.Font.Size = 30;
                    headerRange.Text = "Exam Dates for the "+SelectCourse2.SelectedItem.ToString();
                }



                //adding text to document
                document.Content.SetRange(0, 0);
               // document.Content.Text = "Exam Dates :" + Environment.NewLine;

                //Add paragraph with Heading 1 style
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para1 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
                object styleHeading1 = "Heading 1";
                para1.Range.set_Style(ref styleHeading1);
                para1.Range.Text = "Exam Dates";
                para1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();



                //Create a 5X5 table and insert some dummy record
               // Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table firstTable = document.Tables.Add(para1.Range, 4,2, ref missing, ref missing);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table firstTable = document.Tables.Add(para1.Range, 4,2, ref missing, ref missing);

                firstTable.Borders.Enable = 1;

               firstTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Exam Name";
               firstTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Exam Date";

               connection.Open();
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ExamName,Date from Exam where CourseNum='"+SelectCourse2.SelectedValue+"'", connection);
               SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int intRow = 2;

            // Retrieve the data and insert into new rows.
            Object beforeRow = Type.Missing;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                firstTable.Rows.Add(ref beforeRow);
                firstTable.Cell(intRow, 1).Range.Text = reader[0].ToString();
                firstTable.Cell(intRow, 2).Range.Text = reader[1].ToString();
               // firstTable.Cell(intRow, 3).Range.Text = reader[2].ToString();
                intRow += 1;
            }




                   // Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;
                //Save the document
                object filename = @"C:\\Users\\Rawan Mansour\\Desktop\\temp1.docx";
                document.SaveAs2(ref filename);
                ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)document).Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)winword).Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);


                MessageBox.Show("Document created successfully !");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: The requirement from the last phrase is rather unclear, you possibly won't get answers if you don't make it clearer. An example of what you want would help here.

Comment: I edited it, but no one answer me can you help me??

Answer (score 1):

I found the Solution : by put the range (1,2)